# using 'solve' on vector valued function

Tags: matlab

I have a vector-valued function defined like this:

```
eqns =@(z) [0.2178*z(7) + 1.96*sin(z(1)) == -0.2*z(9)*cos(z(1)),...
             0.7*z(9) + 1.5*z(4) + 0.2*z(7)*cos(z(1)) - 0.2*z(2).^2*sin(z(1)) == z(5)]
```

This is a set of two equations where I want z(7) and z(9) to become the subject of the formulae. That is to say, I want these two equations in the form z(7) = f1(z(1),z(2),z(3),z(4),z(5)) and z(9) = f2(z(1),z(2),z(3),z(4),z(5)).

I tried to do this:

```
[f1,f2]= solve(eqns,z(7),z(9))
```

but it gives me the error "Undefined function 'z' for input arguments of type
'double'."

Any help will be much appreiated

Comment: `z` has not been defined. It is only available from *within* your anonymous function `eqns`

Comment: Also, `solve` is meant to work with inputs that are ["specified as a symbolic expression or symbolic equation"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html?refresh=true#inputarg_eqn), which an anonymous function is not.

Comment: Just a comment. z if defined as a symbolic vector:

Comment: that is to say 'syms z'

Comment: thank you for your responses. When I define 'z' as I've done above (syms z). I get the error 'index exceeds matrix dimensions'. I placed the line 'size(z) just to check and it returned 1*1.

Comment: That's because `syms z` doesn't define `z` as a vector; it is a `1x1` symbolic variable.  You need to do `z = sym('z',[9,1]);`.

Comment: Thanks Troy. When I define it like that,  i get  the error: In 'symbolic:solve:errmsg1', data type supplied is
incorrect for parameter {1}. And I have no idea what that means.

Answer (score 1):

Without a declaration of `z` as a symbolic variable, Matlab doesn't know what `z` is when it tries to evaluate `z(7)` and `z(9)` in the call to solve.  Therefore, `z` must be defined prior to the call and also the definition of `eqns`.  Further, since you are treating `z` as a vector, it is easiest to declare it using [`sym`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html#bu1rqnb-1) rather than `syms`:

```
z = sym('z',[9,1]);
```

Lastly, as mentioned in the comments, the first input to `solve` is to be ["specified as a symbolic expression or symbolic equation"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html?refresh=true#inputarg_eqn), so **do not** declare `eqns` to be an anonymous, vector-valued function as you would do, for example, [`fsolve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html); simply define it using Symbolic Variables, and it will be a Symbolic Expression by construction.

All that said, this code produces an answer for me:

```
z = sym('z',[9,1]);
z([1,2,4,5]) = sym(rand(4,1));
eqns = [0.2178*z(7) + 1.96*sin(z(1)) == -0.2*z(9)*cos(z(1)),...
        0.7*z(9) + 1.5*z(4) + 0.2*z(7)*cos(z(1)) - 0.2*z(2).^2*sin(z(1)) == z(5)];
[f1,f2]= solve(eqns,z(7),z(9));
```

Comment: Thanks Troy. I must say, as a first time user of stackoverflow, I was very pleasantly surprised at the speed of your response.

Comment: @Sedzani You can do even better by paying it forward and accepting Troy's answer. This lets the StackOverflow community know you no longer need help for this particular question --> [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)